# How to Display EDGE only?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

Is there a way to only show a selected edge without the color gradient? In blender 2.93, with only (1) edge selected there is some kind of Color Spaghetti gradient. I just want to see the single edge.
something more like the Silo image on right: [image]

Comment: It's maybe a theme setting? I have the "Spaghetti gradient" only in *vertex* selection mode not in *edge* selection mode when using the default dark blender theme.

Comment: Ha! ok then, will check in Preferences? Do you also know how to: Change Selected Edge size and Color? the only thing found so far is changing size for everything.